# discord.js 'guildMemberAdd' Event not working despite turning on Intents

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

This is my first question here, so I apologize in advance if I'm doing something wrong.

As you may know, Discord recently implemented some changes which made it necessary to activate Privileged Gateway Intents so that bots can keep welcoming new members and giving them roles.

My bot is in a single server, so I granted it both PRESENCE INTENT and SERVER MEMBERS INTENT. I was under the impression that this should be enough to get the bot to start working as normal again, but sadly it still doesn't welcome new members nor does it give it their custom role. Everything else works as normal though (it responds to !nameofthebot), and the bot is online. I also manually gave it all necessary permissions in the channels where I want them to be active.

I'm not very knowledgeable in code and I built this bot thanks to reading discussion here and on other sites. As such, I'm wondering if maybe there's something that needs an update on this level, too. Here's the code in question:

```html
require('dotenv').config()

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});


client.on('guildMemberAdd', function(member) {
  member.guild.channels.get("539191415624826903").send(`Welcome to our server <@${member.user.id}>. Please do not forget to read the rules, and if you have time, don't hesitate to tell us a little about yourself.<:__:551298213622317066>`)
 var role = member.guild.roles.get("549670094079524867");
 member.addRole(role)
});

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

I double-checked the channel and member IDs and they should be fine. Just in case this can be of help, the code is hosted on GitHub and the bot runs thanks to Heroku.

Thank you in advance to anyone who may be able to help me figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 4):

For guildMemberAdd, guildMemberRemove, guildMemberUpdate events you need to enable "GUILD_MEMBERS" intent

Please check [this link](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)

this is how I am creating my bot client:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");  
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

client = new BotClient({
  ws: { intents: [Intents.NON_PRIVILEGED, "GUILD_MEMBERS"] },
});
```

OR

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");  
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

client = new BotClient({
  ws: { intents: Intents.ALL },
});
```

Please also make sure you have enabled PRIVILEGED Intents on your [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Comment: Thank you for this! I did enable all Privileged intents on the Developer Portal, but when I try your code, it tells me "ReferenceError: Intents is not defined".

Comment: I tried to define the Intents, but the bot still does not react to new members joining. Here's my new code:

Comment: `const Discord = require("discord.js");

const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({ ws: { intents: Intents.ALL }});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("I am ready");
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', function(member) {
  member.guild.channels.get("636919952787374092").send(`Welcome to our server <@${member.user.id}>.`)
 var role = member.guild.roles.get("637288616057503749");
 member.addRole(role)
});`